# Sessions not saving after facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

So i have followed the below mentioned tutorial to integrate the PHP facebook SDK into my sites login system.

[tutorial](http://earlysandwich.com/programming/php/how-to-retrieve-facebook-profile-information-with-php-sdk-v3-167/)

I've pretty much got it working, but have fallen at the final hurdle! When i login i am redirected to the logged in page and all my session variables are still there `$_SESSION['loggedin'], $_SESSION['userid'] etc`. When i click on a link to navigate to another page all but one (a facebook session variable that I cannot seem to locate originates from) of the session variables disappears, effectively logging the user out again. 
below is the code on my process login page that checks if the user exists and sets the loggedin session if they do to log them in.

```
 $check_user_exists = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE fb_id = '$fb_id' OR    email = '$email'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_user_exists) > 0)
{
    //if fbid or email is found in users table, get user info
    $get_user = mysqli_fetch_array($check_user_exists);
    //if the user does not have a facebook id in the table
    if(!$get_user['fb_id'])
    {
        //update users facebook id
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET fb_id = '$fb_id' WHERE userid = '{$get_user['userid']}'");
    }


    //set logged in session and session userid

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $get_user['userid'];
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET online = 'online', last_ip = '{$IP}' WHERE userid = '{$get_user['userid']}'");
          /*print"<a href='index'>click here to continue</a>";  
          var_dump($_SESSION);    */           
    header("Location: index"); 
    exit;
}
```

I have `session_start()` at the top of all of my pages and have searched extensively for some kind of solution but can't seem to find anyone who's had the same issue. It's getting extremely frustrating now!

It would also appear that before i login with facebook (on my login page) i have one session id, but after using the facebook login i have a different session id. Could this be causing the session variables to get lost? when i use my normal login system, the session is the same on my login page and all the pages after login.